# Asp.net HashPassword() error

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash

Ok I am at the end of rope now. I am creating a project(website) for my degree college and that requires authentication of the user. I have decided to use ASP.NET's hashing functionality for security. I am using salt too.
Now the problem is i am unable to verify whether the password is correct or not, since the HashPassword() method always gives a different hash, even if my stored hash and salt are the same.

Here's the code for that:

1)  signup.aspx.cs ( if you can find some error there )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class signup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void SignUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String username = Request.Form["username"].Trim();
        String password = Request.Form["password"].Trim();
        String emailaddress = Request.Form["emailaddress"].Trim();
        String salt = Crypto.GenerateSalt(128);
        String hashedpassword = Crypto.HashPassword(salt + password);

        InsertData(username, password, emailaddress, salt, hashedpassword);
    }

    private void InsertData(string username, string password, string emailaddress, string salt, string hashedpassword)
    {
        String connectstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EpicsoString"].ConnectionString;
        result1.InnerText = connectstring;
        String enter = "INSERT INTO USERS ( USERNAME, EMAILADDRESS, PASSWORD, SALT ) VALUES ( @UN, @EA, @HP, @S )";
        result1.InnerText = "username: " + username + "\nPassword: " + password + "\nEmailAddress: " + emailaddress + "\nSalt: " + salt + "\nhashedPassword: " + hashedpassword;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectstring);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(enter, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UN", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = username;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EA", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = emailaddress;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HP", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = hashedpassword;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@S", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = salt;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

2)  login.aspx.cs This is the actual login page that is generating the error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = Request.Form["username"];
        string password = Request.Form["password"];
        VerifyData(username, password);

    }

    private void VerifyData(string username, string password)
    {
        String connectstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EpicsoString"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT Password, Salt FROM USERS WHERE UserName = @UN";
        string dbpassword = "";
        string dbsalt = "";
        string hash = "";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectstring);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UN", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = username;

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (sdr.HasRows)
            {
                if(sdr.Read())
                {
                        dbpassword = sdr["password"].ToString();
                        dbsalt = sdr["salt"].ToString();
                        hash = Crypto.HashPassword(dbsalt + password);
                    result.InnerText = " dbsalt: " + dbsalt + " " + " dbpassword: " + dbpassword + " " + " hash: "+hash;

                        if (Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(dbpassword, password))
                        {
                            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successful.');</script>");//Authentication Successful
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Not Successful.');</script>");//Authentication Unsuccessful
                        }
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sorry, an error occured for some reason. Please try again');</script>");
        }
    }

}
```

Even the VerifyHashedPassword() is not authenticating.
I was debugging so the hash variable.
This is my first time here, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am not. Only hash is stored on the database with column name "password" for a tini-bit more security. i am retrieving the hash and salt and both are done successfully. Only problem is new hash is created for the same salt and the same password whilst i want the old hash generated.

Comment: Okay just another thing, I have stored both salt and password column with nvarchar(128) datatype and i am retrieving as string. Will it affect the comparison somehow?